Power spectra - change of time resolution
I have a question regarding the spectral analysis. I got power spectra (of measured electromagnetic waves) with a time resolution $\Delta t = 1s$ and a frequency resolution $\Delta f = 1Hz$, however, I need a time resolution 2 seconds. The highest possible resolution is even higher and data I can get depend on the parameter the provider sets (he does the Fourier transformation). I was suggested to integrate the date to get my desired resolution. But I am not sure what exactly this means theoretically or practically. Probably not just averaging.
My solution probably would be just take the average of each of two data points or interpolate the lower resolution data on the higher resolution data.

What does frequency resolution of $2$ seconds mean? Why is your frequency in seconds?

A mistake, it is a time resolution

Could "integrate the data" mean take the inverse Fourier and then take every other sample?

DTFT (discrete time Fourier transform) of a sample sequence taken at $T=1s$ is periodic with a periodicity of $\frac{1}{T} = 1Hz$. You have power spectrum with a resolution of $1$Hz. This means you just have the average power for the entire unique spectrum. The other values will be repeat. I don't know what you can do with one sample per full spectral range.

Another note. Decimation in time results in an aliasing of the original spectrum. Imagine values $a$ and $b$ from different parts of spectrum added. If you only had the information of $a^2$ and $b^2$, you can't compute $(a+b)^2$. That is the case of having just PSD of original signal and that too with such a low resolution (if my calculation in previous comment is right). I think I may not have understood your available data fully.

Sampling frequency is something like 78 kHz
